# unreported exception java.io.IOException at actionlistener

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception

I am new to java and I am trying to make it to when a button is pushed, it will update the new information that was put in the table. I am getting this error:

```
unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Here the code I'm having trouble in:

```
public static void updateAction(){

update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmp));
 for(int i = 0 ; i < table.getColumnCount() ; i++)
 {
 bfw.write(table.getColumnName(i));
 bfw.write("\t");
 }

 for (int i = 0 ; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
 {
 bfw.newLine();
 for(int j = 0 ; j < table.getColumnCount();j++)
 {
 bfw.write((String)(table.getValueAt(i,j)));
 bfw.write("\t");;
 }


 }
  bfw.close();

 }});     
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods of [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) throw an [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html). You must either catch it in your method body or declare your method to throw it.

Since you are using an anonymous implementation of `ActionListener`, you can't change the signature of  `actionPerformed`. So you must catch the `IOException` inside of `actionPerformed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch like this

```
try {
   ....
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

or throws IOException at

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
```